# Tensorflow Serve - Correct JSON signature

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to get the correct JSON payload to consume via JSON REST a Tensorflow Serve model, that is supped to have as input an array with an array of two float.

Here is the medatata:

```
{
  "model_spec": {
    "name": "saved_model.pb",
    "signature_name": "",
    "version": "3"
  },
  "metadata": {
    "signature_def": {
      "signature_def": {
        "serving_default": {
          "inputs": {
            "inputs": {
              "dtype": "DT_FLOAT",
              "tensor_shape": {
                "dim": [
                  {
                    "size": "-1",
                    "name": ""
                  },
                  {
                    "size": "23",
                    "name": ""
                  },
                  {
                    "size": "2",
                    "name": ""
                  }
                ],
                "unknown_rank": false
              },
              "name": "lstm_1_input:0"
            }
          },
          "outputs": {
            "prediction": {
              "dtype": "DT_FLOAT",
              "tensor_shape": {
                "dim": [
                  {
                    "size": "-1",
                    "name": ""
                  },
                  {
                    "size": "1",
                    "name": ""
                  }
                ],
                "unknown_rank": false
              },
              "name": "dense_1/BiasAdd:0"
            }
          },
          "method_name": "tensorflow/serving/predict"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried many different JSON structures but for the moment nothing likes to Tensorflow Serve.
What is needed to uniquely identify the necessary payload?

Comment: Hi welcome to Stackoverflow. Try including some/one of the JSON structures you have tried and explain how it is not working for you.

Comment: Can you give more information regarding your Dataset like names of features, and if possible, top 5 rows of your Dataset so that we can try forming JSON for inference.